# Drools persistent fact handle

Tags: java, drools

I am serializing & deserializing DROOLS sessions using the marshaller. It seems to be working as expected. Something I notice however, is that previously create fact handles, no longer works when trying to retrieve facts on the deserialized session.

Test below fails because fact variable equals null. Please note that below code is pseudocode, just to convey the idea.

```
Customer c = new Customer();

KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession();
FactHandle h = kSession.insert(c);

byte[] bytes = marshaller.marshall(kSession);

KieSession restoredSession = marshaller.unmarshall(bytes);
Object fact = restoredSession.getObject(h);

Assert.assertEquals(c, fact);
```

The reason why I would like to keep/re-use the handle, is so that I could retrieve facts in a consistent way across a distributed environment.

Any idea how I could achieve this?

Update:

I also tried M. Prokhorov's suggestion.

```
Customer c = new Customer();

KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession();
FactHandle originalHandle = kSession.insert(c);

String externalHandle = h.toExternalForm();

byte[] bytes = marshaller.marshall(kSession);

KieSession restoredSession = marshaller.unmarshall(bytes);

FactHandle restoredHandle = DefaultFactHandle.createFromExternalFormat(externalHandle)

Object fact = restoredSession.getObject(restoredHandle);

Assert.assertEquals(c, fact);
```

Thanks

Comment: Might be a dumb question, but: What is a `Customer`, and does it override `equals()`?

Comment: Customer is domain object/fact. It implements serializable & implements its own equality ie. equals & hashcode. I am able to serialize/deserialize the session, just not able to retrieve the fact with its original handle.

Comment: Ah, I missed that `fact` variable is `null`. It's possible that handles somehow bind to the session object (I don't know, since I'm only looking at Javadocs here). What I suggest is try calling `toExternalForm()` on original handle, and then use `DefaultFactHandle.createFromExternalFormat` on returned String.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried exactly what you are recommending, still no luck. It seems like when the DefaultFactHandle get created, it uses System.identityHashCode(object) to create the fact handel identityHashCode. After the session gets deserialized, the fact handles have new identityHashCode. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: It does make sense to me, and it's a bummer. I don't have any further suggestions then, lets see if some else has an answer.